# Get Columns Number in Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a script in Vba which once users select some cells gives me column numbers of those cells? Thanks. For example, user selects cells (A1,B3) , I want to have A and B columns as an output.

Comment: "I want to write a script in Vba" - permission granted! :)

Comment: what do you mean by `output` .... you have to use detailed description because `output` can mean many things ... column A has over a million cells alone

Comment: I mean the result of the Script. when I run my script, can  print Column A & B are selected . or print Column 2 & 3& 4 are selected .

Comment: Welcome @Maryam!  You might find that your questions will get more assistance (and fewer down-votes) if you provide as much detail as possible. It's tough to image what exactly you're trying to do, based on 2 sentences.  Could you post a screenshot or some code showing what you have, what you need to happen, and what you've tried?  More tips for question-writing here: [ask]

Comment: @ashleedawg thanks for suggestion, this Time I get my answers but for next time for Sure I do that. Many thanks :)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Not Funny :| :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range.Rows` and `Range.Columns` return a collection cells grouped into Rows or Columns respectively.  Knowing this we can simple iterate over the `Columns` in the `Selection`.

```
Sub Msgbox_ColumnsInSelection()
    Dim rColumn As Range
    Dim s As String
    For Each rColumn In Selection.Columns
        s = s & rColumn.column & ","
    Next
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    MsgBox "Columns in Selection: " & s
End Sub
```

---

This will check if a column is in a range.

```
Function hasColumn(Target As Range, vColumn As Variant)
    hasColumn = Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Columns(vColumn)) Is Nothing
End Function
```

### Usage

> Msgbox "Column 10 is in the range = "  hasColumn(Selection,10)
>
> Msgbox "Column A is in the range = "  hasColumn(Selection, "A")

Comment: Thanks So much :) works well for me :)

Comment: can you please help me how can I check that in S we have column 1 or not ? I mean, How can I check by if condition that there is column 1 in S or not? Many Appreciated .. @Thomas Inzina

Comment: You should take your time and write a detailed question showing your code attempts.  This will yield much better answers to your question. You should also watch this series: [Excel VBA Introduction - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: @ Thomas Inzina Thanks for your link. found it really helpful. I just started my code and now it just prints the column suer selects (the code you gave me).The next step, I want to do is ,check if column 1 is selected or not.

Comment: Many thanks, Helpful ..

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the Selection object to see what was selected. Here is a code snippet from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203726(office.11).aspx):

```
Sub Count_Selection()
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For Each cell In Selection
        count = count + 1
    Next cell
    MsgBox count & " item(s) selected"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Thomas Inzina can you please help me how can I check if there is Column 1 in that s list? Much appreciated